# Create a CFTree in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I want to create a basic CFTree with some string info in Objective-C.

This is my code

```
//CFtree attempt
NSString *info;
CFTreeContext ctx;

NSString *treeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"the tree string"];
info = treeString;

ctx.info = info;
CFTreeRef myTree = CFTreeCreate(NULL, &ctx);
```

I get an "EXC_BAD_ACESS" error on the last line.
Can someone please tell me how to configure this properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that ctx should be initialized.

```
ctx.version = 0;
ctx.info = info;
ctx.retain = CFRetain;
ctx.release = CFRelease;
ctx.copyDescription = CFCopyDescription;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to initialize the ctx struct to 0 before using it since there are members in it that otherwise may cause erratic behavior as the CFTreeCreate thinks they are pointing to something relevant.

[see](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTreeRef/Reference/reference.html)