# Error : "Use of undeclared identifier 'CFTree'"

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-foundation

I am creating tree in `iOS` application using `CFTree`. I am getting error "Use of undeclared identifier '`CFTree`'". What I am missing?
My code :

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    CFTree tree = CreateMyTree(kCFAllocatorDefault);
}

static CFTreeRef CreateMyTree(CFAllocatorRef allocator) {
    NSString *info = @"Bhushan is great";
    CFTreeContext ctx;
    ctx.version = 0;
    ctx.info = (__bridge void *)(info);
    ctx.retain = CFRetain;
    ctx.release = CFRelease;
    ctx.copyDescription = NULL;
    return CFTreeCreate(allocator, &ctx);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type is `CFTreeRef`, not `CFTree`:

```
CFTreeRef tree = CreateMyTree(kCFAllocatorDefault);
```

Comment: thanks, do you have any reference links for creating complex trees?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *info;
CFTreeContext ctx;

NSString *treeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"the tree string"];
info = treeString;

ctx.info = (__bridge void *)(info);
CFTreeRef myTree = CFTreeCreate(NULL, &ctx);
```

this is the link:[Create a CFTree in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106162/create-a-cftree-in-objective-c)